# How to print numbered variables

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have the following variables:

`display1 display2 display3 display4`

and I want to print their containings in one line. I use the following command but I cannot understand why it is not working:

`for((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do printf '%s ' "$display$i"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Your code evaluates the output of two variables `$display` and `$i`. Since `$display` is probably not set, you only see the output of `$i`.

Assuming you're using `bash`, you can use variable indirection of the form `${!varname}`. First, create new variable containing the desired variable name and then use the indirection

```
for((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
  varname=display$i
  printf '%s ' "${!varname}"
done
```

or use a *nameref* variable declared with `declare -n` which is a name reference to another variable

```
for((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do
  declare -n ref=display$i
  printf '%s ' "$ref"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!